# Is It possible to render a realtime physic animation on a website?

Tags: animation, game-physics, phaser-framework

I want to create an Interactive website, but I have doubts that It won't even run on decent computers.

Summary;
I want to create a bird simulation, from top view (Birds don't need to be detailed).
People will be able to drag the birds around, and the crowd will follow them, therefore every single bird must calculate something simultaneously. I wanted to make this in a Website so more people could interact with it. But if it's not possible before starting, I want to switch.

Comment: People have run 3d first person shooters in the browser, so it's probably possible. That said, this is pretty much impossible to answer -- you know your app and audience best. For example of the ambiguity here, is there 30 birds? 3000000 birds? The first is much more doable, the second... might require some thought. But then again, maybe those 30 birds each have 300000 parameters that need to be updated 60 times a second... who knows? What's a "decent" computer specifically?

Comment: I was not giving enough information sorry, I am not planning to make a complicated one, yeah maybe 30 birds, with a 3 4 parameters to check. So from my understanding, It's highly possible, Only thing is finding the right structure and framework for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, is possible in to build this with phaser.

If you want to see, phaser functions/features in action, I highly recommend checking out the offical phaser examples, they show most *function/features* in useful and testable examples.

Just go to https://phaser.io/examples, there you can find everything you will need, like [drag-events](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/input/dragging/multiple-draggables), [sprite animation](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/create-animation-from-texture-atlas), and many more.
And on the official page you can even find [tutorials to get started](https://phaser.io/learn) with the development.

Just stick to Phaser 3, since this is the current and stable Version.